# Is it possible to change datatype from list to dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value, type-conversion

If I'm having a list such as `week = [{'Weekdays': 5, 'Weekends': 2}]` ,is it possible to obtain `week = {'Weekdays': 5, 'Weekends': 2}` from the same where datatype of `week` will be `dict`?

Answer (score 0):

Index the list `week = week[0]` and assign

```
In [26]: week = [{'Weekdays': 5, 'Weekends': 2}]

In [27]: week = week[0]

In [28]: week
Out[28]: {'Weekdays': 5, 'Weekends': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure there's a week, then grab it. Do you know there will always be exactly one week?

```
if week: week = week[0]
```